# 80s or 90s movie about two silver girls that came to the Earth from the Moon

Tags: story-identification, movie, moon

I don't remember much about it except one girl is named Tavi. I'm  not sure about the spelling. They had powers like being able to see through eyes of a flying bird. "Sept the bird, Tavi" I remember one said to the other and suddenly camera view was from the bird. There was an Earth boy with a dirtbike whose nickname was Dirt. That's all I remember. Not much to go on, I know.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack exchange :) .. nice 1st question. I know its hard to give details but try to be a little more specific. I recommend you take the [tour] and visit the [help] .

Comment: Was this a live action or animated film?

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223664/80s-90s-scifi-movie-where-an-alien-family-is-stuck-on-earth (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

I am watching this movie right now.

The movie is [**Hyper Sapien: People from Another Star**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091238/)

There is a three-eyed furry orange alien named Kirby, that is meant to be cute but is somewhat terrifying. It has three arms which double as legs. The film moves slowly as the two girls try to fit in but are thwarted by Kirby causing problems. The girls can read minds and pick up language and skills from the people around them. They have huge hair.

[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps snap a picture and show us a snapshot?

Comment: OK just got to the credits. It stars Ricky Paull Goldin as Dirt. I will look him up.

Comment: By IMDB, that would likely be *Hyper Sapien: People from Another Star*, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091238/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_30

Comment: ^_^ Post a link to IMDB, a short bit about how the movie matches, possibly keep the screenshot, and Bob's your Uncle.

Comment: Thanks :) For reference, the movie is terribly, terribly bad. It's like Xanadu without anything that made Xanadu vaguely watchable.

Comment: If you would, just edit this entry to add the information and delete your other answer. There's no penalty for deleting your own answer which has a 0 score.