# 80s/90s Scifi movie where an alien family is stuck on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

When I was younger I remember watching a copied VHS that had a partial sci-fi movie on it. From what I remember a humanoid alien family somehow gets stuck on earth.

There were 2 sisters whose hair changed from white to brunette/blonde in sunlight.

They had an orange fuzzy alien like pet with maybe 3 legs, and it was apparently a young *whatever* and it smoked coal at some point.

I've tried looking for family oriented scifi movies from the 80s/90s and have had no luck finding this title.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168787/sci-fi-movie-from-the-early-80s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*Hyper Sapien: People from Another Star*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091238/?ref_=tt_urv) (1986)

> Robyn is a teenage girl whose people from the planet Taros have been hiding on the Moon, biding their time to assimilate with Earthlings. She grows impatient. Robyn, Tavy (a younger girl) and Kirbi (a furry tripod creature) stowaway on a mission to Earth and sneak away. They are befriended by a Wyoming rancher's son. He hides them at his open-minded grandfather's house while his parents host a senatorial campaign barbecue

One of the reviews mentions the alien pet (seen at the end of the trailer below) drinking petrol.

Comment: One assumes that the bbq will be over coal which the alien can then eat.

Comment: Thank you so much Valorum for the title.

Comment: @Shanny - [Always a pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)